# Limiting SQL Table to only N number of record

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have one **SQLite** table. I want it to store only 1000 rows maximum.

If a new record comes aftre that limit, then it should automatically delete the last row before inserting the new one.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: can you show your table structure? and show what you've tried so far?

Comment: It consist of 3 columns -  Id NUMBER(Primary Key), created_at TIMESTAMP and contents TEXT

Comment: is that id is an `identity` column?

Comment: You could use a **trigger**: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_triggers.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check before you `insert`

Your command should be like this...

```
if ((select count(*) from yourTable)=1000)
   delete from yourTable where id= (select max(id) from yourTable)
   insert into yourTable values(@values...)
else
   insert into yourTable values(@values...)
```